# Space not working in my form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I recently built a website for my clients but the space is not working in form;
Can somebody help me??
http://aimwaytravel.com/aimwayn/items.php?item_id=16

```
/**
 * jQuery Galleriffic plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Trent Foley (http://trentacular.com)
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Much thanks to primary contributer Ponticlaro (http://www.ponticlaro.com)
 */
(function(a){var b={};var c=0;a.galleriffic={version:"2.0.1",normalizeHash:function(a){return a.replace(/^.*#/,"").replace(/\?.*$/,"")},getImage:function(c){if(!c)return undefined;c=a.galleriffic.normalizeHash(c);return b[c]},gotoImage:function(b){var c=a.galleriffic.getImage(b);if(!c)return false;var d=c.gallery;d.gotoImage(c);return true},removeImageByHash:function(b,c){var d=a.galleriffic.getImage(b);if(!d)return false;var e=d.gallery;if(c&&c!=e)return false;return e.removeImageByIndex(d.index)}};var d={delay:3e3,numThumbs:20,preloadAhead:40,enableTopPager:false,enableBottomPager:true,maxPagesToShow:7,imageContainerSel:"",captionContainerSel:"",controlsContainerSel:"",loadingContainerSel:"",renderSSControls:true,renderNavControls:true,playLinkText:"Play",pauseLinkText:"Pause",prevLinkText:"Previous",nextLinkText:"Next",nextPageLinkText:"Next ›",prevPageLinkText:"‹ Prev",enableHistory:false,enableKeyboardNavigation:true,autoStart:false,syncTransitions:false,defaultTransitionDuration:1e3,onSlideChange:undefined,onTransitionOut:undefined,onTransitionIn:undefined,onPageTransitionOut:undefined,onPageTransitionIn:undefined,onImageAdded:undefined,onImageRemoved:undefined};a.fn.galleriffic=function(e){a.extend(this,{version:a.galleriffic.version,isSlideshowRunning:false,slideshowTimeout:undefined,clickHandler:function(b,c){this.pause();if(!this.enableHistory){var d=a.galleriffic.normalizeHash(a(c).attr("href"));a.galleriffic.gotoImage(d);b.preventDefault()}},appendImage:function(a){this.addImage(a,false,false);return this},insertImage:function(a,b){this.addImage(a,false,true,b);return this},addImage:function(d,e,f,g){var h=typeof d==="string"?a(d):d;var i=h.find("a.thumb");var j=i.attr("href");var k=i.attr("title");var l=h.find(".caption").remove();var m=i.attr("name");c++;if(!m||b[""+m]){m=c}if(!f)g=this.data.length;var n={title:k,slideUrl:j,caption:l,hash:m,gallery:this,index:g};if(f){this.data.splice(g,0,n);this.updateIndices(g)}else{this.data.push(n)}var o=this;if(!e){this.updateThumbs(function(){var a=o.find("ul.thumbs");if(f)a.children(":eq("+g+")").before(h);else a.append(h);if(o.onImageAdded)o.onImageAdded(n,h)})}b[""+m]=n;i.attr("rel","history").attr("href","#"+m).removeAttr("name").click(function(a){o.clickHandler(a,this)});return this},removeImageByIndex:function(a){if(a<0||a>=this.data.length)return false;var b=this.data[a];if(!b)return false;this.removeImage(b);return true},removeImageByHash:function(b){return a.galleriffic.removeImageByHash(b,this)},removeImage:function(a){var c=a.index;this.data.splice(c,1);delete b[""+a.hash];this.updateThumbs(function(){var b=f.find("ul.thumbs").children(":eq("+c+")").remove();if(f.onImageRemoved)f.onImageRemoved(a,b)});this.updateIndices(c);return this},updateIndices:function(a){for(i=a;i<this.data.length;i++){this.data[i].index=i}return this},initializeThumbs:function(){this.data=[];var b=this;this.find("ul.thumbs > li").each(function(c){b.addImage(a(this),true,false)});return this},isPreloadComplete:false,preloadInit:function(){if(this.preloadAhead==0)return this;this.preloadStartIndex=this.currentImage.index;var a=this.getNextIndex(this.preloadStartIndex);return this.preloadRecursive(this.preloadStartIndex,a)},preloadRelocate:function(a){this.preloadStartIndex=a;return this},preloadRecursive:function(a,b){if(a!=this.preloadStartIndex){var c=this.getNextIndex(this.preloadStartIndex);return this.preloadRecursive(this.preloadStartIndex,c)}var d=this;var e=b-a;if(e<0)e=this.data.length-1-a+b;if(this.preloadAhead>=0&&e>this.preloadAhead){setTimeout(function(){d.preloadRecursive(a,b)},500);return this}var f=this.data[b];if(!f)return this;if(f.image)return this.preloadNext(a,b);var g=new Image;g.onload=function(){f.image=this;d.preloadNext(a,b)};g.alt=f.title;g.src=f.slideUrl;return this},preloadNext:function(a,b){var c=this.getNextIndex(b);if(c==a){this.isPreloadComplete=true}else{var d=this;setTimeout(function(){d.preloadRecursive(a,c)},100)}return this},getNextIndex:function(a){var b=a+1;if(b>=this.data.length)b=0;return b},getPrevIndex:function(a){var b=a-1;if(b<0)b=this.data.length-1;return b},pause:function(){this.isSlideshowRunning=false;if(this.slideshowTimeout){clearTimeout(this.slideshowTimeout);this.slideshowTimeout=undefined}if(this.$controlsContainer){this.$controlsContainer.find("div.ss-controls a").removeClass().addClass("play").attr("title",this.playLinkText).attr("href","#play").html(this.playLinkText)}return this},play:function(){this.isSlideshowRunning=true;if(this.$controlsContainer){this.$controlsContainer.find("div.ss-controls a").removeClass().addClass("pause").attr("title",this.pauseLinkText).attr("href","#pause").html(this.pauseLinkText)}if(!this.slideshowTimeout){var a=this;this.slideshowTimeout=setTimeout(function(){a.ssAdvance()},this.delay)}return this},toggleSlideshow:function(){if(this.isSlideshowRunning)this.pause();else this.play();return this},ssAdvance:function(){if(this.isSlideshowRunning)this.next(true);return this},next:function(a,b){this.gotoIndex(this.getNextIndex(this.currentImage.index),a,b);return this},previous:function(a,b){this.gotoIndex(this.getPrevIndex(this.currentImage.index),a,b);return this},nextPage:function(a,b){var c=this.getCurrentPage();var d=this.getNumPages()-1;if(c<d){var e=c*this.numThumbs;var f=e+this.numThumbs;this.gotoIndex(f,a,b)}return this},previousPage:function(a,b){var c=this.getCurrentPage();if(c>0){var d=c*this.numThumbs;var e=d-this.numThumbs;this.gotoIndex(e,a,b)}return this},gotoIndex:function(b,c,d){if(!c)this.pause();if(b<0)b=0;else if(b>=this.data.length)b=this.data.length-1;var e=this.data[b];if(!d&&this.enableHistory)a.historyLoad(String(e.hash));else this.gotoImage(e);return this},gotoImage:function(a){var b=a.index;if(this.onSlideChange)this.onSlideChange(this.currentImage.index,b);this.currentImage=a;this.preloadRelocate(b);this.refresh();return this},getDefaultTransitionDuration:function(a){if(a)return this.defaultTransitionDuration;return this.defaultTransitionDuration/2},refresh:function(){var a=this.currentImage;if(!a)return this;var b=a.index;if(this.$controlsContainer){this.$controlsContainer.find("div.nav-controls a.prev").attr("href","#"+this.data[this.getPrevIndex(b)].hash).end().find("div.nav-controls a.next").attr("href","#"+this.data[this.getNextIndex(b)].hash)}var c=this.$imageContainer.find("span.current").addClass("previous").removeClass("current");var d=0;if(this.$captionContainer){d=this.$captionContainer.find("span.current").addClass("previous").removeClass("current")}var e=this.syncTransitions&&a.image;var f=true;var g=this;var h=function(){f=false;c.remove();if(d)d.remove();if(!e){if(a.image&&a.hash==g.data[g.currentImage.index].hash){g.buildImage(a,e)}else{if(g.$loadingContainer){g.$loadingContainer.show()}}}};if(c.length==0){h()}else{if(this.onTransitionOut){this.onTransitionOut(c,d,e,h)}else{c.fadeTo(this.getDefaultTransitionDuration(e),0,h);if(d)d.fadeTo(this.getDefaultTransitionDuration(e),0)}}if(e)this.buildImage(a,e);if(!a.image){var i=new Image;i.onload=function(){a.image=this;if(!f&&a.hash==g.data[g.currentImage.index].hash){g.buildImage(a,e)}};i.alt=a.title;i.src=a.slideUrl}this.relocatePreload=true;return this.syncThumbs()},buildImage:function(a,b){var c=this;var d=this.getNextIndex(a.index);var e=this.$imageContainer.append('<span class="image-wrapper current"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#'+this.data[d].hash+'" title="'+a.title+'"> </a></span>').find("span.current").css("opacity","0");e.find("a").append(a.image).click(function(a){c.clickHandler(a,this)});var f=0;if(this.$captionContainer){f=this.$captionContainer.append('<span class="image-caption current"></span>').find("span.current").css("opacity","0").append(a.caption)}if(this.$loadingContainer){this.$loadingContainer.hide()}if(this.onTransitionIn){this.onTransitionIn(e,f,b)}else{e.fadeTo(this.getDefaultTransitionDuration(b),1);if(f)f.fadeTo(this.getDefaultTransitionDuration(b),1)}if(this.isSlideshowRunning){if(this.slideshowTimeout)clearTimeout(this.slideshowTimeout);this.slideshowTimeout=setTimeout(function(){c.ssAdvance()},this.delay)}return this},getCurrentPage:function(){return Math.floor(this.currentImage.index/this.numThumbs)},syncThumbs:function(){var a=this.getCurrentPage();if(a!=this.displayedPage)this.updateThumbs();var b=this.find("ul.thumbs").children();b.filter(".selected").removeClass("selected");b.eq(this.currentImage.index).addClass("selected");return this},updateThumbs:function(a){var b=this;var c=function(){if(a)a();b.rebuildThumbs();if(b.onPageTransitionIn)b.onPageTransitionIn();else b.show()};if(this.onPageTransitionOut){this.onPageTransitionOut(c)}else{this.hide();c()}return this},rebuildThumbs:function(){var b=this.data.length>this.numThumbs;if(this.enableTopPager){var c=this.find("div.top");if(c.length==0)c=this.prepend('<div class="top pagination"></div>').find("div.top");else c.empty();if(b)this.buildPager(c)}if(this.enableBottomPager){var d=this.find("div.bottom");if(d.length==0)d=this.append('<div class="bottom pagination"></div>').find("div.bottom");else d.empty();if(b)this.buildPager(d)}var e=this.getCurrentPage();var f=e*this.numThumbs;var g=f+this.numThumbs-1;if(g>=this.data.length)g=this.data.length-1;var h=this.find("ul.thumbs");h.find("li").each(function(b){var c=a(this);if(b>=f&&b<=g){c.show()}else{c.hide()}});this.displayedPage=e;h.removeClass("noscript");return this},getNumPages:function(){return Math.ceil(this.data.length/this.numThumbs)},buildPager:function(a){var b=this;var c=this.getNumPages();var d=this.getCurrentPage();var e=d*this.numThumbs;var f=this.maxPagesToShow-1;var g=d-Math.floor((this.maxPagesToShow-1)/2)+1;if(g>0){var h=c-g;if(h<f){g=g-(f-h)}}if(g<0){g=0}if(d>0){var i=e-this.numThumbs;a.append('<a rel="history" href="#'+this.data[i].hash+'" title="'+this.prevPageLinkText+'">'+this.prevPageLinkText+"</a>")}if(g>0){this.buildPageLink(a,0,c);if(g>1)a.append('<span class="ellipsis">…</span>');f--}while(f>0){this.buildPageLink(a,g,c);f--;g++}if(g<c){var j=c-1;if(g<j)a.append('<span class="ellipsis">…</span>');this.buildPageLink(a,j,c)}var k=e+this.numThumbs;if(k<this.data.length){a.append('<a rel="history" href="#'+this.data[k].hash+'" title="'+this.nextPageLinkText+'">'+this.nextPageLinkText+"</a>")}a.find("a").click(function(a){b.clickHandler(a,this)});return this},buildPageLink:function(a,b,c){var d=b+1;var e=this.getCurrentPage();if(b==e)a.append('<span class="current">'+d+"</span>");else if(b<c){var f=b*this.numThumbs;a.append('<a rel="history" href="#'+this.data[f].hash+'" title="'+d+'">'+d+"</a>")}return this}});a.extend(this,d,e);if(this.enableHistory&&!a.historyInit)this.enableHistory=false;if(this.imageContainerSel)this.$imageContainer=a(this.imageContainerSel);if(this.captionContainerSel)this.$captionContainer=a(this.captionContainerSel);if(this.loadingContainerSel)this.$loadingContainer=a(this.loadingContainerSel);this.initializeThumbs();if(this.maxPagesToShow<3)this.maxPagesToShow=3;this.displayedPage=-1;this.currentImage=this.data[0];var f=this;if(this.$loadingContainer)this.$loadingContainer.hide();if(this.controlsContainerSel){this.$controlsContainer=a(this.controlsContainerSel).empty();if(this.renderSSControls){if(this.autoStart){this.$controlsContainer.append('<div class="ss-controls"><a href="#pause" class="pause" title="'+this.pauseLinkText+'">'+this.pauseLinkText+"</a></div>")}else{this.$controlsContainer.append('<div class="ss-controls"><a href="#play" class="play" title="'+this.playLinkText+'">'+this.playLinkText+"</a></div>")}this.$controlsContainer.find("div.ss-controls a").click(function(a){f.toggleSlideshow();a.preventDefault();return false})}if(this.renderNavControls){this.$controlsContainer.append('<div class="nav-controls"><a class="prev" rel="history" title="'+this.prevLinkText+'">'+this.prevLinkText+'</a><a class="next" rel="history" title="'+this.nextLinkText+'">'+this.nextLinkText+"</a></div>").find("div.nav-controls a").click(function(a){f.clickHandler(a,this)})}}var g=!this.enableHistory||!location.hash;if(this.enableHistory&&location.hash){var h=a.galleriffic.normalizeHash(location.hash);var j=b[h];if(!j)g=true}if(g)this.gotoIndex(0,false,true);if(this.enableKeyboardNavigation){a(document).keydown(function(a){var b=a.charCode?a.charCode:a.keyCode?a.keyCode:0;switch(b){case 33:f.previousPage();a.preventDefault();break;case 34:f.nextPage();a.preventDefault();break;case 35:f.gotoIndex(f.data.length-1);a.preventDefault();break;case 36:f.gotoIndex(0);a.preventDefault();break;case 37:f.previous();a.preventDefault();break;case 39:f.next();a.preventDefault();break}})}if(this.autoStart)this.play();setTimeout(function(){f.preloadInit()},1e3);return this}})(jQuery)
```

Comment: By space do you mean spacebar? If so then you need to check out in other browser and other computer as well because it is working fine at my end

Comment: really?? let me check!! did input in name works in your side?
like James Bond

Comment: Yes i did work at my end

Comment: No its not working!!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FqI7nU8.jpg

Comment: Never before have I seen such a low quality question that violates so many of the guidelines for posting here coupled with a slew of equally low quality answers that should not even be posted as answers... Flags for everybody.

Comment: @ wobbles: thanks for the complement but still its not taking space  I checked in few browsers and in few laptops. i suspect you too don't know the answer why its happening that's why you just keep flagging... anyway still looking for proper answer. 

i think it works in small devices but its not working in pc and laptops

Comment: Anil, I don't think it is clear what you are asking, so this question will likely close. When asking questions we do need all the relevant information in the question itself. This is because fixing the problem on your website will result in this question not being useful for anyone else in the future.

Comment: No, actually you were flagged due to the fact that your question does not meet the guidelines for posting here. No legitimate developer is going to put any effort into answering a question posted like this.

Comment: Thankyou to all for your valuable time for responding my question. (which looks silly but) anyway can somebody tell me the reasons why space doesnt work in browser??

Comment: @Wobbles, I agree this question does not meet the guidelines, but if you can get into the habit of being civil notwithstanding, I think it will help. Be nice here `:-)`

Comment: You have soo many javascript files running! Somewhere there a callback is striping spaces from your form! It seems like you've just added plugins and used them without actually reading their documentation and knowing what they do. Did you build this with a drag and drop builder?

Comment: I used java plugin for date picker and prettyphoto that all but it works perfect in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem but not sure if it is yours. If you disable JavaScript, then you can add spaces so definitely a `.js` file causing this issue! You have so many JavaScript files all the time that makes it very difficult to track a specific problem but in your `jquery.galleriffic.min.js` there are some keyboard mappings and space is one of them.

So looking at their sources [here](https://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/source/browse/trunk/example/js/jquery.galleriffic.js) on line `933` we see the following code:

```
// Setup Keyboard Navigation
if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation) {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    switch(key) {
      case 32: // space
        gallery.next();
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
      case 33: // Page Up
        gallery.previousPage();
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
      // and some more cases!
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: once deleted 
<script src="js/jquery.galleriffic.min.js"></script>

it started taking space but again arise another problem. not displaying the image!!
:(

Comment: Of course it won't display the image because you have deleted it's javascript support `:D`. Open your jquery,galleriffic.min.js and remove `case 32: blahblah break;`, You can search the file with the keyword `keydown` and find that part. Or simply replace the number `32` with another key number from this list: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

Comment: Lots and lots of thankyou my friend!! It worked!! 
Thankyou sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo sooooo much!!
Really helped!! Thankyou for you kindness and effort!!

Appreciated!!